# ModelAdmin related issues in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

Below is my code within the admin.py file.

```
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title', 'organization',)}
    save_as = True

admin.site.register(Job, JobAdmin)
```

**Issue #1:**

I'm trying to prepopulate my slug using 2 different fields. The title field is getting populated correctly, whereas the organization field is a foreign key field, which is also getting populated but with an integer value. I would like to have this field populated with its original value which is the name field within the Organization model. To achieve this, I did try changing the organization field as follows:

```
class JobAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title', 'organization__name',)}
```

But this is giving me an error.

```
ERRORS:
<class 'jobs.admin.JobAdmin'>: (admin.E030) The value of 'prepopulated_fields["slug"][0]' refers to 'organization__name', which is not an attribute of 'jobs.Job'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

**Issue #2:**

The `save_as = True` does not enable the “Save as new” button. I did refer to the [Django Admin Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) but I'm unable to comprehend what else needs to be done to enable this.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me in fixing these issues. Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1:

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields), prepopulated fields is done via Javascript. The syntax you're using is a Django ORM syntax. I don't think you can use a related fields property there. You can only use the properties on the given model.

> When set, the given fields will use a bit of JavaScript to populate from the fields assigned.

Issue 2:

That's all you should have to do. Is it possible you were looking for the button when you were creating a new Job?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding @schillingt. Issue 2: Yes, I'm expecting one of the button to be replaced with the "Save as new" button.

Comment: From what I understand that button only appears when you're editing an instance. Are you sure you were on the correct page?

Comment: Thank you so much again. My mistake I was confused. Now I'm able to find it! You're are lifesaver :)